# How do I determine the PC offset of a LC-3 machine

Tags: assembly, lc3

In a homework assignment we are trying to trace the code of a LC-3 machine
The first line of code is
0x3000 1110 001 000011111
which is a LEA to destination of R1.
I am lost by the PC offset. If I read it right it is 31 in decimal or 1F in hex. But the range we are given to get info from is 0x3020 through 0x3025. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried reading our book and going over lecture notes, but the instructor just gives us an answer  without explaining how he gets it.

Comment: The PC has already been incremented to point to the next instruction, so an offset of 0x1F from the address 0x3001 is 0x3020.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the PC offset — it is 31.

What you're looking for is the *effective address* (aka memory location) that is referred to by a PC offset of 31 from an instruction located at 0x3000.

For `LEA` (and the others that use `PCoffset9`) this is defined as:

`effectiveAddress` = `PC`<sup>1</sup> + `SEXT`(`PCoffset9`)

and for LEA then, `DR` = `effectiveAddress`

where the LEA instruction has the format:

```
1110:4 DR:3 PCoffset:9
```

- 1110:4 is the 4-bit opcode for `LEA`
- `DR`:3 is the 3-bit number of the target register
- `PCoffset`:9 as a 9-bit immediate number

<sup>1</sup>The incremented PC.

From location 0x3000, the incremented PC is 0x3001, while `SEXT(31)` is 31, so 0x3001 + 31 is the value computed into `R1`.